# Capistrano 3 rollback missing tutorial

Tags: capistrano3

How can we do rollback in capistrano tasks. I just checked tutorial here http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks/. It seems missing. Please help with code examples. How can we do rollback all tasks if any task is failed?

Does anyone have previous experience in Capistrano 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good point on the missing docs. I've created a first draft of such documentation here: https://github.com/capistrano/documentation/pull/148

Feel free to read it over and provide comments.

Thanks!